# Draw Ellipse in Swift using UIBezierPath

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6, uibezierpath

I have an `UIViewController` in which I want to draw a ellipse on the screen starting at `CGPoint(x:160,y:160)`, width:`240`, height:`320`. How can I do that in swift?
I would really much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I believe this is what you are asking for:

```
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(160, 160, 240, 320))
UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
```

For complex shapes I would suggest checking out [PaintCode](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/). It creates the swift code for you as you draw your shapes on screen (it has personally saved me a lot of time in the past).

Edit:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class CustomOval: UView {

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
            var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(0, 0, 240, 320))
            UIColor.grayColor().setFill()
            ovalPath.fill()
    }

}
```

Then :

```
var exampleView = CustomOval()
```

And then position it with constraints etc. afterwards.

**Swift 4**

```
var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 240, height: 320))
UIColor.gray.setFill()
ovalPath.fill()
```

Comment: Thank for your answer but where do I have to write that code in? So I do in my viewDidLoad function:

Comment: The code above and then e.g.: UIColor.blackColor.setStroke(); path.lineWidth = 5; path.stroke;

Comment: Well I tried the code from you and myself -> I got lots of errors: ... invalid context 0x0 ...

Comment: I generally create a custom object (subclass of UIView or the like) to hold the bezier object itself. Check my answer for the updated code. Then I create an instance of that class and add it to my main view.

Comment: I don't think you need to import Foundation any more.

Comment: Swift 3 update:

`let ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rectForOval)`

Answer (score 4):

Write this code in **override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)** in Custom UIView, then edit as you want.

```
override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
    let ellipsePath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 200))

    let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    shapeLayer.path = ellipsePath.CGPath
    shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0

    self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
}
```

Comment: Swift 4 `let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = ovalPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)`

Answer (score 1):

```
let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
shapeLayer.path = ovalPath.cgPath 
shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor 
shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0
self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
```

Comment: Where are you getting ovalPath from?

Comment: oval path is the path of your view you can initialise it like :-  var ovalPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 160, y: 160, width: 240, height: 320)) @Womble